# Istio exclusion policy

Tags: kubernetes, istio, istio-sidecar

Can somebody explain what this policy means, i have been trying for full day but didnt get in the proper way

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
 name: test-dev-only-authorized-api
 namespace: istio-system
spec:
 action: DENY
 rules:
 - from:
   - source:
        notRequestPrincipals: ["*"]
   to:
   - operation:
       paths: ["/message/ping"]
```

Request to pls mention namespace relevance too. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's a deny policy that denies any request from any namespace to any workload in the `istio-system` namespace that does not have any request principal like jwt token when the path is `/message/ping`.